# Dangling branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, remote-branch

It's probably an already asked question, but I just don't know what are the right names to call the issue - so please guide me or answer (yes, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658885/how-do-you-get-git-to-always-pull-from-a-specific-branch) question but couldn't get too much from the answer).

I am trying to `git pull` but receiving the following message:

```
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.2012_05_09_my_branch.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:
    [branch "2012_05_09_my_branch"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

It probably looks like my working directory is kinda "hanging" without being attached to any branch, am I right? If so - please advice on how to get it connected back to the proper branch (`2012_05_09_my_branch` for example). Probably I am even wrong with that (being a total GIT newbie), in this case please explain what's happening and what can I do about it.

Refined question: what do I need to do to run `git push` and `git pull` successfully without getting the message above?

**Update:** when I run `git branch` I get:

```
* 2012_05_09_my_branch
  master
```

Which *kinda* probably means that I am on my local `2012_05_09_my_branch` branch which is not connected to any of the remote branches?

**Update N2:** [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time) - very worth reading as a complementary material (found only now).

Comment: `git branch --set-upstream <your remote>/2012_05_09_my_branch 2012_05_09_my_branch`   Note: <your remote> is probably `origin`

Comment: >>>_Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?_ - To create your local branch use: `git checkout --track remotes/<remote>/<branch>` . This will create local branch named `<branch>` and upstream will be set automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* that your working dir is not attached to a branch, but you do not have setup what is peer branch on the remote for your local branch. You can "connect" them together with:

```
git branch --set-upstream 2012_05_09_my_branch remotes/<your remote>/2012_05_09_my_branch
```

Where < your remote > is the server server as defined in .git/config, usually (when working with one server) is `origin`

***EDIT:*** the safer way is to use `remotes/<remote>/<branch>` instead of `<remote>/<branch>`

Comment: thanks! sounds like this! will try it very soon and will mark the answer when it works. meanwhile - any idea on how could I get to this (strange for me) situation (where a branch becomes "unconnected")? I know and use only very basic commands (promise to improve in the near future :)

Comment: also, how can I know that any local branch is attached to the proper remote branch - which command do I need to run to get the info please?

Comment: @BreakPhreak `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) <- %(upstream:short)' refs/heads` If there local branch not connected to remote you will get `<local branch> <-`

Comment: and to the question on how a branch can become "unconnected" (please)?

Comment: @BreakPhreak I can not answer that question, there are many ways: 1) changing your `.git/config` 2) deleting then recreating the local branch 3) not setting it as _tracking_ branch in first place. etc, etc, etc

Comment: thanks (underrstood). now applied your command and updated the main question (something is still /*done*/ wrong).

Comment: PS: IF you can - please look at "Update N2"

Comment: sorry, the arguments should be swapped. please read my updated answer answer, and redoit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12099/discussion-between-breakphreak-and-op-de-cirkel)

Answer (score 0):

```
git status
```

will help you find out on which branch you are (if any). The command

```
git branch
```

will give a list about the local branches you have (git branch -a lists the remote ones as well). And of course you can use

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

to turn your working copy to the chosen branch.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a local branch, and want to put it on remote repository you need to run this command:

```
$ git push origin 2012_05_09_my_branch
```