# Make git pull (rebase) by default pull only from current downstream branch

Tags: git

I am using the method I found to [pull --rebase by default](http://d.strelau.net/post/47338904/git-pull-rebase-by-default) when doing git pull:

Now I want to make the 'git pull' - by default pull only the current branch: [How do you get git to always pull from a specific branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658885/how-do-you-get-git-to-always-pull-from-a-specific-branch). However this answer does not work when git is configured to rebase by default.

Is there a way to make git pull always rebase and pull only current branch?

Comment: Related: [How to make Git pull use rebase by default for all clones?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13846300/456814).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6314060/6309) mentions:

if you have `branch.autosetuprebase = always` then it will also add:

```
rebase = true
```

You can, after doing `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`, configure the rebase attribute of your branch:

```
git config branch.master.rebase false
```

Comment: Ah, I did not see that. Thanks!

Comment: Why would I do "git config branch.master.rebase false"? that would set the rebase flag to false in the .git/config

Comment: @mbdev to avoid git rebasing by default after a `git pull`.

Comment: oh, we have a rebase policy so I would like it to --rebase the git pull

Comment: @mbdev in that case, the `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` is enough: any `git pull` from your branch will still fetch the upstream branch. (and then rebase your branch on top of it)