# Failed to push some refs to remote repository

Tags: git

I create a new remote repository in my LAN and I add the projects （`PROJECT 1`，`PROJECT 2`).

USER A and USER B clone the repository at a time and USER A did the changes in `PROJECT 1` and pushed these changes.

USER B did the changes in `PROJECT 2`,he didn't make any changes in `PROJECT 1` and while pushing the data also he select only `PROJECT 2` content, But it gives error while pushing.

```
ERROR :

error: failed to push some refs to http://gitbub.com
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first merge the remote changes (e.g.,
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`
```

How to allow the push for User 2?

Comment: It looks like `PROJECT1` and `PROJECT2` each need their own repo.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [jcm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794461/jcm), the easiest solution would be for project1 and 2 to be sotred in their own repos.

But if they are in the same repo, then:

User2 still need to rebase his/her work on top of an updated repo.

```
git pull --rebase
```

Compared to `git pull` alone, this allows you to replay your local commits on top of the updated remote tracking branch.

```
x--x--x--x--y--y--y (master): y means Project2 commits
         |
  (origin/master)
```

`git pull --rebase` = `git fetch` + `git rebase`

`git fetch` means:

```
x--x--x--x'--x' (origin/master)
       \
        y--y--y
```

`git rebase` means:

```
x--x--x--x'--x'--y'--y'--y' (master)
             |
      (origin/master)
```

Now a `git push` will be a trivial one, adding your local commits on top of origin master.

Since User2's work was separate from User1's, the rebase will trivially replay User2's commit on top of origin/master, and will allow the ([fast-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/6309)) push.

Since both projects are in the same repo, that situation will arise if they are modified on the same branch.

A good workaround would be to create two branches, one for each project.

If you need both project, then you need to `pull --rebase` before pushing.
You can consider [making the rebase automatic on a `git pull`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445945/6309).

---

Multiple `git pull` alone would introduce merge commits which are not needed here (since the modifications are done on two separate sets of files)

```
x--x--x--x'----x' (origin/master)
       \        \
        y--y--y--m (master)
```

Then the next pull:

```
x--x--x--x'----x'--x'---x' (origin/master)
       \        \        \
        y--y--y--m--y--y--m (master
```