# Pulling from non-default remote

Tags: git

I have two remotes configured for my working copy. One I use regularly - it is called origin. Another I use for occasional backup - it is called assembla. Now when I pull from assembla, I always get this:

```
$ git pull assembla
You asked to pull from the remote 'assembla', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

This is easily resolved like this:

```
$ git pull assembla master
```

but I don't want to add `master` to the command every time I do that.

Is there any way to pre-configure "default" local branch for each remote, to make the command shorter?

Just in case: I don't want to change the default configured remote for this branch, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658885).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get git to always pull from a specific branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658885/how-do-you-get-git-to-always-pull-from-a-specific-branch)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the mentioned question, because the later suggests changing the default configured remote, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in the `addsembla` branch, navigate to your `config` file.  It should be in `/<project>/.git/config`.  Open up an editor (e.g. nano or Vim) and add the following lines:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = assembla
```

Comment: This will change the default remote, so that `git pull` will pull from assembla. This is not what I want.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I misunderstood.  In that case, I would probably take @Melebius approach.  Depending on where your hosting the remote repos, you may be able to set a default branch there.  Not sure if that would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) command.

```
git config alias.pullassembla 'pull assembla master'
```

Then run it using:

```
git pullassembla
```

Of course, you can use another name for the alias.

Comment: Yes, probably a shell alias will also do.