# Can I get the upstream remote branch by ruby-git

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, upstream-branch

I'm using [ruby-git](https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git) to operate my Git repo.  I can get the local branch that checkout from remote branch, how can I get it upstream remote branch? This's the code:

```
require 'Git'
repo = Git.open("xxxpath.git")
localbranch = repo.branches["localbranchnamexxx"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would do it in normal git

```
remote_branch = repo.branches["origin/localbranchnamexxx"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter-intuitively (to me, at least), the branch tracking information is stored in the [git config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658885/how-do-you-get-git-to-always-pull-from-a-specific-branch), not in any branch or ref structures.

```
require 'git'
repo = Git.open("xxxpath.git")
localbranch = repo.current_branch
upstream_remote = repo.config["branch.#{localbranch}.remote"]
upstream_ref = repo.config["branch.#{localbranch}.merge"]
upstream_branch = upstream_ref.split('/').last
upstream = "#{upstream_remote}/#{upstream_branch}"
```